# HTML - Change order of elements in document flow

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

For a responsive design at desktop size I want to have an aside floated right, at the same vertical position as a header, but to sit below my first paragraph for mobile; something Like:

**Desktop**

```
*Header*       | --aside--  |
<P>1, Lorum    | Also Lorum |
Ipsum Dolar</p>| Ipsum, etc.|
<P>2, Sit amet,|____________|
blah, blah, blah, blah.</p>
```

**Mobile**

```
*Header*
<P>1, Lorum
Ipsum Dolar.</p>
| --aside--  |
| Also Lorum |
| Ipsum, etc.|
|____________|
<P>2, Sit amet,
blah, blah,
blah, blah.</p>
```

Currently I have my aside as a column in a multi-column layout (*foundation 5*), which works fine for the mobile layout, but on desktop My second paragraph is on a row below the aside, thus there's a lot of whitespace between paragraph 1 and paragraph 2.

What I want is for my document to display on desktop as if it were:

```
<aside style="float:right;">blah blah.</aside>
<h2>blah</h2>
<p>blah, blah.</p>
<p>blah, blah.</p>
<p>blah, blah.</p>
```

And to display on moblie as if it were:

```
<h2>blah</h2>
<p>blah, blah.</p>
<aside>blah blah.</aside>
<p>blah, blah.</p>
<p>blah, blah.</p>
```

What are my options?

Thanks.

EDIT: To clarify, I am using media queries. The question is about what css rules to use to achive the 2 different layouts with the same HTML.

Comment: Read [Responsive Web Design](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/) by Ethan Marcotte, and then try to implement media queries at different breakpoints.

Comment: if `h2` and first `p` have a known `height` , you can drop `aside` below them using `pseudo-element` , `float` and `clear`, else use `display:flex` and `order` . @nHaskins  make us a fiddle to get example , thks for you

Comment: @GCyrillus, display: flex; and order look like the "correct" solution, but the browser support doesn't seem to be there yet. I'll deffinitley need to read up on this for future projects though.

Comment: @nHaskins the display:table-thingy-thing hint below within answers would work from IE8 . the float trick can break for 1 pixel missing / extra. i guess you have your nowdays answer down here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with media queries and a different display properties. The properties are: table-footer-group, table-row-group and table-header-group ([w3schools display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)). These properties are css equivalents of tfoot,tbody and thead from html. With these properties you can change the display order of some items. Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jb8d/) to check how it works.

This is what it looks like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="aside">
        <aside style="float:right;">This is outside</aside>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>blah</h2>
        <p>blah, blah.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentlast">
        <p>blah, blah.</p>
        <p>blah, blah.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    #aside {
        display:table-row-group;
    }
    #content {
         display:table-header-group;   
    }
    #contentlast {
         display:table-footer-group;   
    }
}
```

The display table row group let the div#aside behave as the tbody. The div#content now behaves as a thead and div#contentlast behaves as tfoot.

Comment: This is conceptually what I'm looking for. I'll try this and see how it works for me.